# Using C# to retrieve stack from bluescreen dump file

Tags: c#, windbg, stack-trace, dump, dmp

I want to know if there is a way of using C# to open a Blue-screen crash dump + loading symbols, in order to retrieve the memory stack.

I know how to do it manually using the program windbg, So if there is a way to connect to Windbg using C# that might solve the problem as well.

Do anyone know how to extract the memory stack using C#, or to connect to Windbg using C#?

Thanks!

Comment: Windbg is using Windows System dll to extract the dump.  So you can go to www.pinvoke.net to get the c# interfaces to the Windows dlls.  You can do a search at pinvoke for debug.

Comment: You can always create a WinDbg [script file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560137(v=vs.85).aspx) and then use C# to create process with command line `windbg -cf myscript.txt -logo mylogfile.txt` and then analyze `mylogfile.txt` using your favorite C# method.

Comment: I would use the script option. The P/Invoke option is challenging for the debugger interfaces.

Comment: Note that there are CorDbg and MDbg, where MDbg is written in C# (less powerpul than CorDbg) but they are both designed to debug managed code, not any crash dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, but i found a much easier way to use it...
Since Windbg can be operated using cmd, it was pretty hard to find and understand the commands, but i managed to operate it using cmd.

After that it is possible to send cmd commands from C#, so i simply sent the command using C#, and wrote the results to file using Windbg's -logo command.

So by reading the file i could parse the results and extract the things that i want.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any C# solution, but [PyKd](https://pykd.codeplex.com/) (Python) can do what you want. While I mainly use PyKd as a plugin for WinDbg,

> It's a Python module and can be used in any Python script

so there's no need for WinDbg.

However, some commands may not work the same way as in WinDbg, e.g. `dbgCommand()` will attempt to run a command of the debugger, which is probably not possible if you work without WinDbg.

From your description, you'll need `loadDump()`, `closeDump()`, `setSymbolPath()` and `setCurrentProcess()`. There are classes for processes and threads and the `sp` (stack pointer) property may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go from scratch and use the dbgeng inerfaces in c#  you may try ecpanding this code i put together

https://github.com/blabberer/chashdbg